# angularjs How to populate selected value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have 2 selected dropdown that is dependent with each other. For example [plunker here](http://embed.plnkr.co/jhu16nyBfZtHcdABi6OT/), I want to populate the value of both dropdown by instead of display "select here" value, I want to display France in first dropdown and One Way in second drop down. I tried `<option value="selectedPlan">{{selectedPlan}}</option>` but it does not show up anything.
Thanks

My code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>



</head>

<body ng-app="selectExample">
  <script>
    angular.module('selectExample', [])
      .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.chooseCountries = [{
          name: "France",
        }, {
          name: "Gibraltar",
        }, {
          name: "Malta",
        }];
        $scope.choosePlans = [{
          plan:"One Way"
        }, {
           plan:"Two Way"
        }];

        $scope.selectedCountry = "";
        $scope.selectedPlan = "";
      }]);
  </script>
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">

    <hr>
    ng-options
    <hr>

    <select ng-model="selectedCountry"
      ng-options="country.name  for country in chooseCountries">
      <option value="">Select here</option>
    </select>

     <select ng-model="selectedPlan" 
      ng-options="plan.plan  for plan in choosePlans">
        <option value="">Select here</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign one of the objects in the options array to the model:

```
    $scope.selectedCountry = $scope.chooseCountries[0];
    $scope.selectedPlan = $scope.choosePlans[1];
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/FqXW3x7uQgy3xTCn5Qbp?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If by "in sync" you mean same index should be selected for second selection, then it would be.

```
<select 
  ng-init="selectedCountry = chooseCountries[0]"
  ng-model="selectedCountry"
  ng-change="selectedPlan = choosePlans[chooseCountries.indexOf(selectedCountry)]"
  ng-options="country.name for country in chooseCountries"> 
</select>
<select 
  ng-model="selectedPlan"
  ng-init="selectedPlan = choosePlans[0]"
  ng-options="plan.plan for plan in choosePlans">
</select>
```

If it's just about initializing selections, say index 0, just leave out `ng-change` above and that's it.